# Cannot save values from form to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, ef-code-first

I am trying to write my first ASP.NET MVC application with Entity Framework (code first).

I am trying to insert data from form to specific table in database but it does not work. When I press "Submit" button, page is refreshing but table still has not any value. There is no error on page or in console.

Could you please take a look on code and help me ?

Below is my code:

**View:**

```
@model VeterinaryApp.Models.Clients

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddClient";
    Layout = "~/Views/SharedViews/_MainLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>AddClient</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Clients</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class AddClientController : Controller
{
    // GET: AddClient
    public ActionResult AddClient()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //POST
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ClientsId, Name, Surname, Email, Phone")] Clients clients)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (StoreContext db = new StoreContext()) //DbContext
            {
                db.Clients.Add(clients);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        return View(clients);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
 public class Clients
    {
        public int ClientsId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BookVisit> BookedVisits { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Animals> OwnedAnimals { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You have not shown your model!

Comment: What code is being executed in your POST method? Is `ModelState` valid or are you just hitting the `return View(clients);` line of code?

Comment: I added model above.

I think that it returns View(clients) because page is refreshed after submit. There is no RedirectToAction(Index).

Comment: That means that `ModelState` is invalid. Debug you code, and check the value of `ModelState` to see what the errors are

Comment: And your GET method is named `AddClient` so your form posts back to a POST method named `AddClient` and you have not shown that method. If you want to post to `Create`, then you need to specify the action name in the `BeginForm()` method

Comment: But there are some awful practices in your code. Your model describes a single client, not a collection, so the model should be named `Client`, not `Clients` (plural). You controller is dealing with actions associated with clients so it should be named `ClientController`, not `AddClientController`, and it will contain methods such as `Index` (for displaying all Clients), `Create`, `Edit`, `Delete` etc and the associated POST methods will have the same name

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. Also I decided to delete controller and view because of bad practices as you said. Now it looks much better - thanks for tips.